# CSS - Position on certain part of a scalable image

Tags: css, background, position, tooltip

I'm currently wire framing a site where there is a large background illustration of a town, and there will be clickable tooltips over certain buildings.

I'm thinking about when it comes to developing the site, is it possible to keep those tooltips over those buildings as the image scales with the browser?

I was thinking percentage positioning but I'm pretty sure that still won't keep the tooltips in the correct location.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: you could do a fine-adjustment of percentages using mediaqueries (unless you really need a pixel perfect position)

Comment: @Paulie_D as I said, I'm in wireframe stage at the minute and haven't so I haven't made any attempts.